# How to check if the user pressed a key inside a Edit controll

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I have a Edit Controll (where u can write stuff) in my code, and I want that when the user will type enter (like in forms of - username / pass), it'll do something..

for example, When you logg into a site and you put ur username and pass, if you click enter, it loggs in automaticly for you, instead of clicking the "connect" button...

I have the following code :

```
ChatHwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "Edit", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_LEFT | ES_MULTILINE | ES_WANTRETURN , 15, 15, 550, 300, hwnd, NULL, 
(HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL); // Creat chat log
```

It's written in Win API...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the ES_WANTRETURN style from the control so the return key will go to the parent dialog. In the parent dialog handle the EN_KILLFOCUS notification (in WM_COMMAND). The wParam that comes with the notification will tell you if if was the edit control you are interested in.

Comment: I've never done anything like that before... could you please show me a bit code? because I am not sure how to use the EN_KILLFOCUS and what to put in the WM_COMMAND too...
Thanks!

Comment: Handling messages from controls is very basic stuff. Find a book or an online tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Dialog the Enter key is automatically handeled in a seperate way.

If you have your own Frame Control and want in Detail a seperate Handling of the Input you have two choices:

1. Use the message Loop and PreTranslate (I use this word from the MFC) the Input Messages.
2. Subclass your control to get Access to all Messages that the control receives.
3. You can use a hook (but that is Overkill)

Comment: I have a dialog, as u can see, I've used the already built in "Edit" class